# Spheres not rendered smoothly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use unity sphere as my GameObject.
but the problem is, sphere edges not rendered smoothly.
[image]

and i don't know can i solve this problem or not?!

Comment: what's the zoom on the editor? u should be able to see a slider. is it > 100%?

Comment: Yes. I sent this picture from my test mobile application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your quality settings on Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality.

Under quality settings, you can set the default quality for your Unity player and other platforms. If the problem is there, increasing the default setting will help.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i set default on ultra and change all to what i want it to be, i mean i dont have light, so i disable them. And set antialiasing to 8x but no improvement that i see...

Comment: Guess the problem is somewhere else.

Let's go through the basic again, just for sure. What are your camera and object size? If the sphere is too small with a very zoomed in camera to render it, something like your problem may appear.

Comment: the main camera's orthographic size is Unity's default size which is 5. I don't know the SVL size right now but I have used Unity's default SVL and have resized it so that the balls match the environment and orthographic 5 and are not small. Do you think orthographic 5 may cause problem here?

Comment: Personally, I usually use ortographic aroud size 10, but just because I feel it's easier to handle de Scene. Try changing it, maybe it will help.

Comment: ... really confused, i change orthographic size to 10 and change sphere size, but yet i have same problem. really appreciate that you try to help solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks pedro. The effect of antialiasing not shown in editor but i see the difference in mobile test. The problem was that i disable antialiasing in quality setting.

Comment: Awesome to know! Nice job, keep up! :D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have anti-aliasing enabled. If that doesn't help enough, use PostProcessing stack and its anti-aliasing as an effect. 
If that's possible in your environment try switching between forward and deferred rendering as well

Comment: i use orthographic camera that cannot use deffered rendering. anti-aliasing is now enable, but nothing changed... and last thing that, i don't want use PostProcessing because of it's performance, because the game is in mobile phones...